# Using PHP while loop to retrieve specific data and post it on a google map

Tags: php, google-maps

Hi im relatively new to PHP and very new to google maps API but I would like to retrieve data from my mysql database and post it onto my google map, the problem is that I need to search database A for relevant data, pull an 'id' from each entry then search database B for all the ids pulled and finally use the data pulled from database B to place a marker on a google map (database B holds the 'id' to correspond with database A a latitude field and a longitude field). I hope all this makes sense after reading my code:

```
<?PHP
    $min = $_POST['min'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM A WHERE x>".$min);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $host=$row['host_id'];
        $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM B WHERE host_id=".$host);
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1));
        {
            $lat2=$row1['latitude'];
            $lon2=$row1['longitude'];
            echo  'var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng('.$lat2.','.$lon2.');';
            echo  'var aMarker = new google.maps.Marker({';
            echo      'position: myLatLng,';
            echo      'map: map,';
            echo  '});';
        }
    } 
?>
```

As I said im pretty new to PHP so any help as to where im going wrong here would be greatly appreciated 
Thanks :)

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Also you're leaving yourself quite open to SQL injection there. You need to sanitise your inputs.

Comment: the map completely disappears, I had it working with 1 while loop that was pulling all of the latitude and longitude data from TABLE B (not database B as I have written) but as soon as I used another while loop to select certain data, using the data from TABLE A the map disappeared from my page :/ any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to two different databases at the same time. With the mysqli_ extension you are using:

```
<?php

$db1 = mysqli_connect('localhost',$username1,$password1);
mysqli_select_db($db1, $database1) or die( "Unable to select database 1");

$db2 = mysqli_connect('localhost',$username2,$password2);
mysqli_select_db($db2, $database2) or die( "Unable to select database 2");

?>
```

Then you can choose either `$db1` or `$db2` as needed.

```
<?php
$min = (int) $_POST['min'];
$result = mysqli_query($db1,"SELECT * FROM A WHERE x>".$min);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $host=$row['host_id'];
    $result1 = mysqli_query($db2,"SELECT * FROM B WHERE host_id=".$host);

    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1));
    {
        //...
    }
}
?>
```

I have added an `(int)` to sanitise your `$_POST['min']` variable - this is important to guard against SQL injection. For strings, you should investigate using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, or even better, go for parameterised queries: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)

**Update**
For tables in the same database, I would recommend reconfiguring your code to use a single SQL statement, and `JOIN` the tables together. Something like:

```
<?php

$sql = "
SELECT B.latitude, B.longitude
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON (A.host_id = B.host_id)
WHERE A.x > {$min}
";

?>
```

This gets all records from B which have a host_id which matches any host_id in A with a value of x greater than $min. You will get duplicates if you have multiple records in A with the same host_id, so you could add a `GROUP BY` clause to reduce these, either on host_id, or on the primary key of table B, if this is not host_id:

```
...
WHERE A.x > {$min}
GROUP BY B.host_id
```

Also, it's probably worth checking the SQL for errors and displaying a warning:

```
<?php

$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($result1===FALSE)
{
    $sql_error = mysqli_error($con);
    $js_safe_sql_error = json_encode(utf8_encode($sql_error));
    echo "alert('Database Error: ' + " . $js_safe_sql_error . ");\n";
}
else
{
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1));
    {
        //...
    }
}

?>
```

I notice in your comment you say that the map completely disappears though. This would indicate an error in the generated javascript. Hopefully your browser's javascript console will display this error. When I run it I get: `ReferenceError: map is not defined`, but this is probably being defined elsewhere in your code?

Comment: firstly thank you for the references to clean my PHP they are much appreciated as the code im writing is all new to me and very rough around the edges in places im sure! Secondly I have to apologise I used the wrong terminology in the question as 'database A' and 'database B' are actually both tables within the same database, i am sorry for the 'rookie' mistake but connecting to the database doesn't seem to be the problem for some reason when i added a second while loop to narrow down the results it makes my map completely disappear and i cannot work out what the problem is with my code...

Comment: Thanks again your code seems much better than mine and as far as i can tell 'works' after alot of playing i have come to the conclusion that my problem is with:

Comment: while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1));
        {
            $lat2=$row1['latitude'];
            $lon2=$row1['longitude'];
            echo  'var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng('.$lat2.','.$lon2.');';

Comment: if i give $lat2 and $lon2 values it works perfectly, and the mysqli query is pulling the correct data for some reason it just wont use it when pulled from the database, its like it cannot translate the data from the cell into a numeric value even though it already is one... I realise that this is probably something really stupid but i really cant get my head around it as far as i can see it should work. I really appreciate your help with this it is sending me crazy trying to get it to work Thanks again

Comment: sorry for the bombardment of comments I have posted the same question written slightly better on this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568236/inserting-mysql-variables-into-google-maps-with-php - hopefully it will be easier to find my downfall on here I would really appreciate if you could have a look. I have included your error message code in mine by the way but taken it out for the question I haven't ignored it, all of your help thus far has been greatly appreciated :)